# Hangfire reduce logging of succeeded jobs

Tags: hangfire

I have 16 recurring jobs similar to below, in a console app running in a Azure Web Job.

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<SendRegisterEmailPoller>(p => p.Poll(), Cron.Minutely);
```

Everytime this runs it drops into the Succeeded Jobs view of the Hangfire UI. 16 of these every minute is going to be useless noise in the succeeded jobs view.

How can I stop either this recurring job or all recurring jobs from being logged in succeeded jobs?

FYI Execute() kicks off

```
if(args != null)
    backgroundJob.Enqueue<SendRegisterEmailJob>(handler => handler.Execute(args));
```

So there will be logging of the Execute process.

Comment: This is by design. Recurring job scheduler is simply a small extension that uses background jobs to execute your tasks. In normal circumstances you'd never look at succeeded jobs page.